# What is the default values of KMP_AFFINITY variable?

Tags: intel, environment-variables

I was playing with the KMP_AFFINITY variable in my program and forgot to back-up the previous value.

Now the performance of my C++ program has fallen to 50%. Can anybody tell me what is the default value of KMP_AFFINITY UBUNTU system.

I tried setting it to blank but the performance is still low.

My OS details are as follows:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Processor Intel 3rd gen Core i5 3210M.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Intel docs](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/cpp/lin/optaps/common/optaps_openmp_thread_affinity.htm):

> ## Affinity Types
>
> Type is the only required argument.
>
> ```
> type = none (default)
> ```
>
> Does not bind OpenMP threads to particular thread contexts; however, if the operating system supports affinity, the compiler still uses the OpenMP thread affinity interface to determine machine topology. Specify `KMP_AFFINITY=verbose,none` to list a machine topology map.